# Calculate the calories and nutrition values for 100g of a cake made from different ingredients

Tags: python, normalization

From a dictionaty of ingredients

```
ingredients = {
    "walnuts": {"calories": 650, "carbs": 13.7, "fats": 65.2, "fibres": 15, "proteins": 6},
    "coconut_flakes": {"calories": 456 , "carbs": 51.8 , "fats": 28, "fibres": 10, "proteins": 3.1},
    "oat_flakes": {"calories": 364, "carbs": 62 , "fats": 5.7, "fibres": 8.5, "proteins": 12 },
    "dates": {"calories": 274, "carbs": 73, "fats": 0.6 , "fibres": 14, "proteins": 1},
    "almonds": {"calories": 577, "carbs": 21, "fats": 49, "fibres": 12, "proteins": 21},
    "sunflower_seeds": {"calories": 572, "carbs": 16, "fats": 46, "fibres": 14, "proteins": 21},
    "peanuts": {"calories": 605, "carbs": 5, "fats": 48, "fibres": 8.5, "proteins": 28},
    "buckwheat": {"calories": 336, "carbs": 68.5, "fats": 1.5, "fibres": 5, "proteins": 9.5},
    "coconut_oil": {"calories": 897, "carbs": 0, "fats": 99.7, "fibres": 0, "proteins": 0},
    "honey": {"calories": 304, "carbs": 82, "fats": 0, "fibres": 0, "proteins": 0},
    "pistachios": {"calories": 605, "carbs": 9, "fats": 49, "fibres": 10, "proteins": 20.5},
    "cashews": {"calories": 553, "carbs": 6, "fats": 44, "fibres": 3, "proteins": 1},
    "sesame_paste": {"calories": 615, "carbs": 0, "fats": 51, "fibres": 7, "proteins": 18},
    "cacao_butter": {"calories": 900, "carbs": 0, "fats": 90, "fibres": 0, "proteins": 0},
    "coconut_milk": {"calories": 200, "carbs": 2, "fats": 21, "fibres": 1, "proteins": 0},
    "rice_milk": {"calories": 60, "carbs": 12, "fats": 1, "fibres": 0, "proteins": 0}
}
```

I want to make different cakes. Every cake will be different and will be made of different ingredients. I want to know the calories and nutritional facts for a normalized slice of 100g.

I tryed this code

```
def calculate_nutritional_values_per_100g(ingredients_dict):
    total_values = {"calories": 0, "carbs": 0, "fats": 0, "fibres": 0, "proteins": 0}
    total_weight = sum(ingredients_dict.values())

    for ingredient, weight in ingredients_dict.items():
        if ingredient in ingredients:
            for key in total_values:
                total_values[key] += (ingredients[ingredient][key] * weight) / 100

    # Normalize for 100g
    normalized_values = {key: round((value / total_weight) * 100) for key, value in total_values.items()}

    return normalized_values

cake_ingredients = { "almonds": 40,
    "sunflower_seeds": 30,
    "peanuts": 25,
    "oat_flakes": 30,
    "dates": 160}
nutritional_values = calculate_nutritional_values_per_100g(cake_ingredients)
print(nutritional_values)
```

with the cake_ingredients from above and the result is {'calories': 326, 'carbs': 51, 'fats': 12, 'fibres': 11, 'proteins': 7}
but the result is wrong. For instance calories should be 386 and not 326.

Comment: I have tried your code and it works fine, it also prints the result you are looking for ```python
{'calories': 386, 'carbs': 53, 'fats': 17, 'fibres': 13, 'proteins': 9}
``` Maybe it was some error during execution?
P.S: The proposed answer someone else has given you is also correct, since you are transforming it to percentages and then turning it back to its original value 

Comment: what do the values in the ingredients dictionary mean? Value per 100 g?

Comment: The values in the ingredients dictionary are for 100g.

Answer (score 2):

You should not need to multiply by 100 because you total mass is absolute, and the standard values are already for 100g:

```
def calculate_nutritional_values_per_100g(ingredients_dict):
    total_values = {"calories": 0, "carbs": 0, "fats": 0, "fibres": 0, "proteins": 0}
    total_weight = sum(ingredients_dict.values())

    for ingredient, weight in ingredients_dict.items():
        if ingredient in ingredients:
            for key in total_values:
                total_values[key] += ingredients[ingredient][key] * weight

    # Normalize for 100g
    normalized_values = {key: round(value / total_weight) for key, value in total_values.items()}

    return normalized_values
```

That said, the two operations cancel and the output is correct.

Output:

```
calculate_nutritional_values_per_100g(cake_ingredients)
# {'calories': 386, 'carbs': 53, 'fats': 17, 'fibres': 13, 'proteins': 9}
```

Alternative version of the code without pre-filling the dictionary:

```
def calculate_nutritional_values_per_100g(ingredients_dict):
    total_values = {}
    total_weight = 0
    for ingredient, weight in ingredients_dict.items():
        for key, val in ingredients.get(ingredient, {}).items():
            total_values[key] = total_values.get(key, 0)+val*weight
        total_weight += weight
    return {key: round(value / total_weight) for key, value in total_values.items()}

calculate_nutritional_values_per_100g(cake_ingredients)
```